# Calculate the difference between expected score and actual score in Python

Tags: python, calculator

I have the following DataFrame in Python:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Person": ["James", "Linn", "James", "Linn"],
                    "Date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-08"],
                    "Exp_Score": ["20", "18", "21", "17"]})
```

I would like to calculate how the expectations change for each person. Baseline for the expectations is the first "Exp_Score" of each person, i.e. on "2022-01-01". For example, expectations for James changed from 20 to 21, indicating that he currently overperforms. I would like to add a new column to calculate the difference on each date and, ultimately, create an overview of each person's over- or underperformance at the end of the year.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Kindly share a sample of your existing code and what isn't working

Comment: You have to provide more code details you have done so far, a good question is always reproduce-able problem, and contains error trace where applicable